# Different Screens/Functionality after login

Tags: mobile, navigation, login

There is an app with screens such as `products`, `events`, `news`; all accessible from bottom navigation. However after logging in the bottom navigation changes and a different set of features are provided e.g. `tasks`, `documents`, and `settings`.

My question: What will be the best way for a users to access the functionality that was available before login without having to first log out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing members, registered users, access to different functions than people who didn't sign up is common, but those are functions that are appended to the normal set of functions.

Eliminating functions after log in is a definite no-go!

I would suggest to add member functions like tasks, documents and settings to the regular set of functions like products, events and news; keeping all of them in the same navigation.

Comment: I totally agree with you Paul, however the client i am dealing with does not like navigation bar with more then 5 items...(he didn't like the more button either) so the solution i have come up with is an icon at the top bar which lets you switch between the before & after login functionality.

Comment: That really is giving me the bad UX shivers. An user shouldn't have to log out to be able to access certain functionalities. What about dividing the two set in two head categories containing sub categories. For example: `Feed` with the newest `products`, `events` and `news` and `advanced` with `tasks`, `documents` and `settings`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a product under development with a similar scenario.

Logged out, the main navigation items available are:

`Home` `About` `Features` `Tour` `Plans` `Contact` `Blog` `Resources` `Support` `Jobs` `Press` `Sign In`

However, once signed in, these are replaced with:

`Home` `Projects` `Support` `Resources` `Blog` `Account` `Sign out`

There is simply no room to have all public & private nav items visible at once. Also, many of those pre-login pages are of little relevance to a signed up customer.

However, logged in users can still access those pages - if they navigate to the `Home` page then the main navigation is the public version, only with `Sign in` replaced with `Projects` and `Sign in`.

Early testing has been favourable with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i see is to have a "home" button in the navigation in both cases user logged in or logged out, and a multi navigation in a case if the user is logged in.

e.g  user logged in,  will see >  home,products,events,news

```
  user logged out will see > home, tasks, docs, settings,
```

but this time an arrow direction upwards will appears on the home tab to let the user know that there is something more on home tab, on tap it will open a tool tip kind of popup or navigation where you can show the remaining items.